# is it possible to specify the pubspec file name when build app in flutter

Tags: flutter

Now I want to build the flutter app with different pubspec file name with different environments, for example:

```
flutter build ios -config dev-pubspec.yaml

flutter build ios -config pro-pubspec.yaml
```

I have read the manual `flutter build ios --help` and did found how to specify the pubspec file name. Is it possible to custom the yaml file name?